# how to display spire.xls chart to html in C#

Tags: c#, html, excel, bar-chart

I'm new in C# programming. Is there a way to display a spire.xls chart to HTML? I want to create stacked bar chart based on the excel table and then display in HTML by using C#. What's the best way to do? 
I was facing the problem of converting the spire.xls chart to a web page. Can anyone help?
Below is my code. Appreciate your help. Thank you

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\310188948\Desktop\Book1.xlsx");
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

        Chart chart = sheet.Charts.Add();
        chart.DataRange = sheet.Range["B2:D18"];
        chart.SeriesDataFromRange = false;
        chart.ChartType = ExcelChartType.BarStacked;
        chart.Legend.Position = LegendPositionType.Right;

        sheet.SaveToHtml("Output.html");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Output.html");

    }
```

Comment: You want to dispaly Xlsx chart to html webpage? Am i correct

Comment: You can save xlsx chart as a image using c#, then load to html webpage as you want...

Comment: what if i save in excel?
 workbook.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\310188948\Desktop\output.xlsx");

Comment: how to load into web page? Below are my code for converting excel file to html but it does not work. It's cant display out the chart. Is there a way to correct it? 
Workbook book = new Workbook();
            book.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\310188948\Desktop\output.xlsx");
            Worksheet sheet1 = new Worksheet();
            sheet1.SaveToHtml("Output.html");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Output.html");

Comment: `Process.Start` will (attempt to) start that process *on the server*. When debugging it might seem to work (because that server is your dev machine running on your own account), but it will not work on a "real" server - the user will never see it.

Answer (score 0):

GemBox's spreadsheet libraries help to convert the .xlsx to HTML format.

```
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;

SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
ExcelFile.Load(@"***path***\filename.xlsx").Save(@"***path***\filename.html");
```

Links for [GemBox](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/) , [libraries](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/free-version), [code samples for .Net](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-library/601)

On installing GemBox, you can find the DLLs for the Dot Net framework in the

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GemBox Software\GemBox.Spreadsheet 4.1\Bin